# Calculate largest value for multiple overlapping events in a specific range

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, longitudinal

I have multiple large data frames that capture events that last a certain amount of time. This example gives a simplified version of my data set

Data frame 1:

```
 ID  Days  Date  Value
  1    10    80     30
  1    10    85     30
  2    20    75     20
  2    10    80     20
  3     5    90     30
```

Data frame 2:

```
   ID  Days  Date  Value
    1    20     0     30
    1    10     3     20
    2    20     5     30
    3    20     1     10
    3    10    10     10
```

- The same `ID` is used for the same person in all datasets
- `Days` specifies the length of the event (if `Days` has the value 10 then the event lasts 10 days)
- `Date` specifies the date at which the event starts. In this case,`Date` can be any number between 0 and 90 or 91 (the data represent days in quarter)
- `Value` is an attribute that is repeated for the number of `Days` specified. For example, for the first row in df1, the value `30` is repeated for 10 times starting from day 80 ( 30 is repeated for 10 days)

What I am interested in is to give for each `ID` in each data frame the highest value per day. Keep in mind that multiple events can overlap and values then have to be summed.

The final data frame should look like this:

```
ID HighestValuedf1    HighestValuedf2
1               60                 80
2               40                 30
3               30                 20
```

For example, for `ID` 1 three events overlapped and resulted in the highest value of 80 in data frame 2. There was no overlap between the events of df1 and df1 for `ID` 3, only an overlap withing df2.

I would prefer a solution that avoids merging all data frames into one data frame because of the size of my files.

**EDIT**
I rearranged my data so that all events that overlap are in one data frame. I only need the highest overlap value for every data frame.

Code to reproduce the data frames:

```
ID = c(1,1,2,2,3)
Date = c(80,85,75,80,90)
Days = c(10,10,20,10,5)
Value = c(30,30,20,20,30)
df1 = data.frame(ID,Days, Date,Value)

ID = c(1,1,2,3,3)
Date = c(1,3,5,1,10)
Days = c(20,10,20,20,10 )
Value =c(30,20,30,10,10)
df2 = data.frame(ID,Days, Date,Value)

ID= c(1,2,3)
HighestValuedf1 = c(60,40,30)
HighestValuedf2 = c(80,30,20)
df3 = data.frame(ID, HighestValuedf1, HighestValuedf2)
```

Comment: Using `data.table` and merging would be quite easy ( can provide code if that is acceptable), if not, you could try finding the unique combinations of `ID` and `Date`. Since the event time is a sum of `Date` and `Days`, that makes things a bit tricky.

Comment: It would be great if you could share your solution to the problem using merging! That would already help.

Comment: Your output does not have a `Date` column?

Comment: How many data frames and rows do you have?

Comment: @Gautam I don't need the date column for my output but feel free to include it in a solution!

Comment: @Paul I have at least 4 data frames and a couple hundred thousand rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am interpreting highest value per day to mean highest value on a single day throughout the time period. This is probably not the most efficient solution, since I expect something can be done with `map` or `apply` functions, but I didn't see how on a first look. Using `df1` and `df2` as defined above:

EDIT: Modified code upon understanding that df1 and df2 are supposed to represent sequential quarters. I think the easiest way to do this is simply to stack the dataframes so anything that overlaps will automatically be caught (i.e. day 1 of df2 is day 91 overall). You will probably need to either adjust this code manually because of the different length of quarters, or preferably simply convert days of quarters into actual dates of the year with a date formate ((df1 day 1 becomes January 1st 2017, for example). The code below just rearranges to achieve this and then produces the results desired for each quarter by filtering on days 1:90, 91:180 as shown)

```r
ID = c(1,1,2,2,3)
Date = c(80,85,75,80,90)
Days = c(10,10,20,10,5)
Value = c(30,30,20,20,30)
df1 = data.frame(ID,Days, Date,Value)

ID = c(1,1,2,3,3)
Date = c(1,3,5,1,10)
Days = c(20,10,20,20,10 )
Value =c(30,20,30,10,10)
df2 = data.frame(ID,Days, Date,Value)



library(tidyverse)
#> -- Attaching packages --------------------------------------------------------------------- tidyverse 1.2.1 --
#> v ggplot2 2.2.1.9000     v purrr   0.2.4     
#> v tibble  1.4.2          v dplyr   0.7.4     
#> v tidyr   0.7.2          v stringr 1.2.0     
#> v readr   1.1.1          v forcats 0.2.0
#> -- Conflicts ------------------------------------------------------------------------ tidyverse_conflicts() --
#> x dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> x dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(Date = Date + 90)

# Make a dataframe with complete set of day-ID combinations
df_completed <- df1 %>%
  mutate(day = factor(Date, levels = 1:180)) %>% # set to total day length
  complete(ID, day) %>%
  mutate(daysum = 0) %>%
  select(ID, day, daysum)

# Function to apply to each data frame containing events
# Should take each event and add value to the appropriate days
sum_df_daily <- function(df_complete, df){
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
    event_days <- seq(df[i, "Date"], df[i, "Date"] + df[i, "Days"] - 1)
    df_complete <- df_complete %>%
      mutate(
        to_add = case_when(
          ID == df[i, "ID"] & day %in% event_days    ~ df[i, "Value"],
          !(ID == df[i, "ID"] & day %in% event_days) ~ 0
        ),
        daysum = daysum + to_add
      )
  }
  return(df_complete)
}

df_filled <- df_completed %>%
  sum_df_daily(df1) %>%
  sum_df_daily(df2) %>%
  mutate(
    quarter = case_when(
      day %in% 1:90 ~ "q1",
      day %in% 91:180 ~ "q2"
    )
  )

df_filled %>%
  group_by(quarter, ID) %>%
  summarise(maxsum = max(daysum))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   quarter [?]
#>   quarter    ID maxsum
#>   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 q1       1.00   60.0
#> 2 q1       2.00   40.0
#> 3 q1       3.00   30.0
#> 4 q2       1.00   80.0
#> 5 q2       2.00   30.0
#> 6 q2       3.00   40.0
```

Comment: In your code you specified the 90 day range. In my example, I used a 30 day range. That's why your solution doesn't come up with the number 80 (it's an overlap of 3 events in the example, 30+30+20). Also, what if the specified date range is between 90 or 91 (or 30 or 31) depending on the month(for example, some quarters are shorter than others)?

Comment: Also, your answer works well for finding the value in every single data frame, but not for events that start in df1 but last into df2.

Comment: You haven't been clear about the relationship between df1 and df2, I think. I don't see which 3 events in the example overlap. The desired answer seems to suggest that you only care about overlaps within a df, but even if you have both dfs on the same timeline there are four events for ID1:value 30 for days 20-29, value 30 for days 25-34, value 30 for days 0-19, and value 20 for days 3-12. No day has overlap of three events.

Comment: You've obviously provided a simplified example, but if you need specific things per month etc. you have to explain what you simplified.

Comment: I updated the example, the simplification wasn't necessary I guess. I hope it is clear now!

Comment: I still don't understand. You changed the dates in df1, but which day of the quarter gives a value of 80 for ID1? Are you saying that each df represents a quarter, and they come one after the other? So you want to know the max value reached by each ID in each quarter, even if the event contributing to that value didn't start in that quarter?

Comment: Exactly. In this case, the event starts in quarter 1 but has an effect into quarter 2. That's why I need to add the effect of quarter 1 into quarter 2 to get the proper value for quarter 2.

Comment: I rearranged my data in a way that I can use your solution. Unfortunately, after a couple of hours, there are still no results.

Comment: I updated the code to reflect your clarification. I suggest you try to understand what each part does, because ultimately you will need to adapt it to your situation. The key conceptual part is creating a table that can hold the max sum on each day, figuring out exactly how you want to show the results or dealing with inconsistencies in df format is more nitty gritty.